# Adding text to Gif file (ios)

Tags: ios, gif

I’m looking for some help/advice on how to add text to an animated gif file /combining  gifs. This app seems to do what I'm trying to do- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pimp-my-text-send-color-text/id489972714?mt=8. So there needs to be the ability to have animated gifs with text on top as well as the ability to add a gif onto another gif.

Here's what my approach will be to accomplish this, I want to make sure it’s the best and most effective way to go about it.

1) Have the initial background as a png sequence of UIImages
2) Draw the text onto each Image
3) Add other Images to each background Image to appear animated as well
4) combine all the background images into one gif

Let me know if I’m on the right path or if there is an easier way to go about this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you want is possible. I don't think that there is any service to add a gif to another gif  because of timing differences. there are many sites online to combine multiple images into a gif and GifBomb from the Appstore on iOS can add headers and text onto gifs. I don't think that this is the site to ask a question like this, try google or a different stack exchange site first.